# How to set request headers for all js-files for caching in extjs?

Tags: javascript, java, caching, extjs, client-server

.js-files are downloading from server side but not from browser cache every time I reload a page with the following headers:

```
Response headers: Cache-Control:max-age=31556926
Request headers: Cache-Control:max-age=0
```

If I click somewhere to load a new panel which was already loaded before page reload, this panel (its .js-file) will be received from the cache.

If to reload this page which already contains that cached panel, all the .js-files including that panel will be once again downloaded from the server.

I'm using Chrome for debugging, "Disable cache" checkbox is not checked.

The question is how to force all .js-files including ext-all.js be cached after the page reload?

Could the server side be a cause?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, when pressing (or invoking) browser reload, all components of the page are always loaded from the server (not from cache).

Comment: in addition, if to click F5 to refresh the page, files are loading from server, but if to highlight the url and click Enter, everything will be loaded from cache.